# Redirigir a otra pagina pasando argumentos en Django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-views

Estando en una vista al cumplirse una condición quiero cambiarme a otra view pasandole la lista *items*:

```
return render(request, 'item/informe.html', {'items': items})
```

Todo parece correcto pero el problema es que me muestra el contenido de la vista `informe` pero dentro de la pagina anterior (la *url* no cambia).

Si cambio por `return HttpResponseRedirect('/informe', {'items': items})` navega bien, pero ya no me pasa la lista *items*. Entiendo que `HttpResponseRedirect` no permite pasar los parámetros de esta forma, quizás alguien sepa ¿cómo se puede hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Saludos te sugiero realizar del siguiente modo usando el metodo **GET**:

Desde donde redirigiremos seria algo así:

```
nombre = 'Diego'
direccion = 'Ecuador'
return redirect('/mi_url/?nombre=' + nombre + '&direccion=' + direccion)
```

bien ahora la **VISTA** donde recibe será algo como esto:

```
def vista_recibeContext(request):
  data = {
      'nombre': request.GET.get('nombre'),
      'direccion': request.GET.get('direccion')
  }
  return render(request, 'mi_template.html', data)
```

**Solución 2:**

Para esto puedes usar **session**

Desde donde redirigimos seria:

```
def Vista1(request):
  .....
  request.session['nombre'] = 'Diego'
```

Ahora donde recibo seria:

```
def Vista2(request):
 ....
 nombre = request.session.get('nombre')
```

Pruebalo y me comentas, espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Antes de todo muchas gracias por tu respuesta. El problema es que al intentar pasar un queryset no me sirve ninguno de los dos métodos. 1º es solo para strings y el segundo me lanza el siguiente error "Object of type 'QuerySet' is not JSON serializable" voy a intentar pasarlo a json y te cuento.